# Character Creation. Cartoon look, Eyes and Extra Parts. What advantages are the combining to one mesh?

Tags: texture, uv-mapping, model

I am fairly new to CG and 3d art. I'm trying to learn to make good game assets (ie. Low poly count, clean looking) in a cartoon style.

I'm making this character as pictured. But his eye is a separate mesh. If I want to join it together I need to add extra edges to the whole model that otherwise aren't needed.

[image]

For this particular game, the eyes, mouth etc doesn't need any animation.

My question is, are there any advantages to finding a way to join the eye hemi-sphere to the face mesh, or is it fine just to leave it like this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Hi, I_Keep_Trying. Similar to my comments on your other question, I think this one is too subjective as it is currently written. Instead of "should I ... ?", it would be better as "are there any advantages to ... ?" That would move it out of opinions and into objective territory. Also, the part about texture maps probably needs to be in a separate question to keep this one focused. I think we have some expertise on this site that can help you get where you're going, it's just that these questions need a little tweaking to fit with our Q/A format.

Comment: fair enough. Funny how small changes in wording makes all the difference. But i do take your point and good advice for the suggested edit